# How to refactor props data being passed in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing data props to two components which are exactly the same like this :

```
export default function Home({ data }) {
    return (
        <Layout title="Home Page">
                    <CarouselMobile
                        aig={data.aig}
                        audi={data.audi}
                        bt={data.bt}
                        francetelecom={data.francetelecom}
                        hkt={data.hkt}
                        kelly={data.kelly}
                        mobinnet={data.mobinnet}
                        orange={data.orange}
                        pccw={data.pccw}
                        sap={data.sap}
                        tata={data.tata}
                        teleperformance={data.teleperformance}
                        wf={data.wf}
                    />
                    <CarouselDesktop
                        aig={data.aig}
                        audi={data.audi}
                        bt={data.bt}
                        francetelecom={data.francetelecom}
                        hkt={data.hkt}
                        kelly={data.kelly}
                        mobinnet={data.mobinnet}
                        orange={data.orange}
                        pccw={data.pccw}
                        sap={data.sap}
                        tata={data.tata}
                        teleperformance={data.teleperformance}
                        wf={data.wf}
                    />
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

How can I refactor this data code which is being passed to both components so it doesn't look messy like this ?

Comment: you can use an array where you can for each

Comment: why not passing just `data` to the components. Then you have all providers in them.

Comment: @Oyeme Can u answer a detailed example of ur suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just spread it if the names are equal.

```
<CarouselMobile {...data} />
<CarouselDesktop {...data} />
```

If not you can also partially spread props with the same name in your data object and the component, and apply other props which have different names.

```
<CarouselMobile {...data} differentProp={differentProp} />
<CarouselDesktop {...data} anotherDifferentProp={anotherDifferentProp} />
```

Or based on the comments, you can also pass the entire `data` object like below.

```
<CarouselMobile data={data} />
```

But the point here is that you would access attributes in `CarouselMobile` with `data.aig` for instance like below.

```
const CarouselMobile = ({ data }) => {
  const { aig, audi, /* other props */ } = data; 
};
```

Comment: How can I make the ...data object ?

Comment: @MaxwellFisher nothing to do, just do `<CarouselMobile {...data} />`. You have all you properties in data, just spread it and you will get all your attributes in you component which you pass `data`

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can create a common object with these props and send that object to both components.

Or you can send `data` prop to the components and use there directly.

Another way, send data prop by using spread operator.

Comment: How can I make the ...data object ?